# Does the size of anylogic elemnets can be changed while zoomIN++/ZoomOUT-- in GIS simulation as it does for the "GIS Regions"?

Tags: gis, anylogic

In Anylogic while running the GIS simulation model, the ZoomIn++/ZoomOut-- does not change size of Anylogic agents (for ex: car/train/bus) used into the model based on GIS map of Anylogic?

How it could be achieved? Does it offer any solution or property to anylogic elements for the relative size W.R.T. ZoomIn/ZoomOut property of GIS Model, as it follows for the "GIS Regions" (The size of GIs regions changes with GIS ZoomIn/ZoomOut)!!

Possible solutions, if exists!! /or Reasons/Restrictions behind?

[ZoomIn Photo the size of elements is same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osvaH.png)

[ZoomOut Photo the size of eements is same and full of mess not Easy to visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5yfb.png)

Answer (score 1):

so first, please watch this video i made on how size works in an AnyLogic gis map:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAZo91lq44M

What I don't say on that video, is the answer to your question directly, which works only for 3D objects... What you need to do is to change the scale:

agent.Object3D.setScale(yourScale);
if you want to make them half the size, yourScale=0.5
for twice the size, yourScale=2

But AnyLogic is not able to identify when you zoom in/zoom out, so you have to do it manually, unless you use `map.ZoomIn()` method to do that.

Comment: Hello Felipe, Thank you so much for your responce but i am struggling with it, i tried to use your method in the same way [you can say i copied your approach of map.zoomIn()/map.zoomOut() by using buttons] but really the problem is still there. Look at the following images attached in my answer please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually i want to change the size of my agents ( agents become larger when I Zoom IN or at least remains the same size as of scale) and (agents MUST become smaller while i Zoom Out)  in my GIS model

Comment: you need to do agent.Object3D.setScale(yourScale) when you zoom/in or zoomout

Comment: Now the things are moving towards betterment and good understandings but here is one error  "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field"    for the code      car.car.setScale(0.2);

Comment: this error you can find an answer in 50 other different questions... search "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field" on google or stackoverflow